How to stop my computer from crashing and restarting when opening the appearance tab in ubuntu 24.10?
After installing ubuntu 24.10 recently whenever I open the appearance tab, the screen freezes and the computer restarts. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop the problem persists. How to rectify this problem because I am unable to change the color scheme of desktop without it.

The same thing happened while using my Settings app because my graphics card was defective. If you're quick about it sometimes you can press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+Del to log out before Ubuntu reboots.
Replacing the graphics card solved the issue. Fortunately it was a discrete graphics card, so I could easily remove it from its slot and replace it with a new graphics card.
The Files app was also taking too much time to display thumbnail images of PDFs and images before I replaced the graphics card. Replacing the graphics card fixed that problem too.
